# Calling PECL function from symfony2 by ``

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony2 and [trader](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php) which is installed from PECL.

I have comnfirmed this library is called from both CLI and web application like this

**Pattern A)**

Without symfony I can call like this.

called.php

```
<?php
$test = array(1,2,3);
$b = \trader_bbands($test,3); //works
$b = trader_bbands($test,3); //works
var_dump($b);
```

from.php

```
<?php
$result = `php ./called.php >>./log.txt`;
```

It works.

**Pattern B)**

However from symfony framework,

```
$b = \trader_bbands($test,3); // it works
$result = `php ./called.php >>./log.txt`; // it shows the error below.
```

show this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function trader_bbands() in /Users/bear/myApp/src/Acme/TopBundle/MyServices/MyFunc.php on line 69

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]         
  Attempted to call function "trader_bbands" from the global namespace.
```

Does anyone have idea to solve this?

Comment: Are the php.ini's within `apache/` and `cgi/` and `cli/` equal? Can `symfony2` handle cli-calls? Handles `symfony2` this call in the same way?

Comment: Look here https://github.com/Cilex/Cilex   CLI Tool based on  Symfony2 components

Comment: What the curious point is when I type in command-line `$>sh ./_calcFromPhp.sh >> log.txt 2>&1 &` works well, but from symfony `shell_exec("sh ./_calcFromPhp.sh >>./log.txt 2>&1 &");` ,error ocurrs

Comment: `which php` -> `usr/local/php5/bin/php -rwxr-xr-x 1 myName admin 13318508 5 15 2015 /usr/local/php5/bin/php` . `php --version` `PHP 5.6.9 (cli) (built: May 15 2015 13:05:42) `Then I checked phpinfo.php, I am not sure which php apache uses. (Does this log mean php is included in apache??->) `SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/5.6.9 `

Comment: `sympony2` has its own server-tool (like apache),sympony does so many stuff, read the documentation from it. think cant help more here.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try to that way though, for now I updated the article to simplify the problem.